# Access HTML-Element-Attributes over Google Chrome-Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google Chrome Extension, which should auto-complete a form on a foreign website, for this to work, I need to access the value of the textboxes.

The following code is executed on a button click note that it takes the current open tab to perform its action the text box on this tab should be filled with some data the opening of the tab works but the value change on the textbox doesnt, how could it be done differently?

```
function autofill() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
       code: "document.getElementById('txbx_name').value = 'Johnny Bravo';"        
    });
}
```

**Manifest**

```
{
    "name": "CopBot",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "CopBot",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
          "storage",
          "tabs",
          "<all_urls>"
        ],

    "background":{
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

How can I access and modify the value of an  element from my Google Chrome Extension?

Comment: Can you add some more information on when this code this executed? Is it from a browser action? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Do you have proper host permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Keyword: _complete_ example. You're saying _"The following code is executed on a button click which opens a new tab containing a form"_ - there are potential timing issues with that that's impossible to guess unless you show the whole chain from the click handler to your `autofill`.